# Is it possible to consume a WebApi REST service using HTML5?

Tags: c#, html, rest, web-services, asp.net-web-api

What I really want to know is what the title says, if is it possible to consume a WebAPI Rest services (e.g. a CRUD made by me) using HYML5? I ask this because if I try to use an ActionResult in any WebApiController, the framework doesn't let me do it. What can I do? Or, what do you advise me to do?

Comment: You can't do it using HTML5 alone. Can you share your code sample?

Comment: @ImranArshad you can issue GET by using image/script/css  or even plain click on a link... But indeed very strange requirement - maybe OP will clarify what they mean as "using HTML5".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

CRUD means Create, Update, Delete.

HTML is nothing more than a markup language, not a programming language per se.

If you want to send requests to an API and then do something meaningful with the results then you will need to use a programming language.

Simplest option would be to use some JavaScript to deal with the requests and then do something with the data.

Answer (score 0):

No, HTML5 is markup language it's used for design only. You can consume WebAPI using programming language only.

Consume using: JavaScript, TypeScript, JQuery and Angular